# YouTube data api v3: unsigned long returned as unicode string

Tags: youtube-data-api

According to the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#resource-representation) the response document for channel resource could have the following object:

```
"statistics": {
    "viewCount": unsigned long,
    "commentCount": unsigned long,
    "subscriberCount": unsigned long,
    "hiddenSubscriberCount": boolean,
    "videoCount": unsigned long
}
```

I tried to call the API but it returned:

```
"statistics": {
    "commentCount": "4", 
    "hiddenSubscriberCount": false, 
    "subscriberCount": "300151", 
    "videoCount": "94", 
    "viewCount": "103656"
}
```

As you can see, `unsigned long` (int) are returned as `string`. Where am I wrong?